# C++ Precedence and Associativity

Tags: c++, pointers, computer-science, operator-precedence

This piece of code:

```
int scores[] {1,2,3,4};
int *score_ptr {scores};  
//let's say that initial value of score_ptr is 1000
std::cout<<*score_ptr++;
```

produces the output:

```
1
```

As `*` and `++` have same precedence and then associativity is from right to left shouldn't we apply `++` operator first that is to increase the pointer first and then `*`(dereference) it?

So accordingly `score_ptr` will be increased to `1004` and then dereferencing it will give the second element of scores which is `2`.

How and why does this give me output of `1` instead of `2`?

Comment: There's a problem with the term "associativity". It's only used once in the C++ 17 standard, and that's in a note that describes how to parse an expression. The rules for how expressions like `*score_ptr++` are evaluated fall out of the grammar productions in the standard. Precedence and associativity "rules" (used in informal descriptions of the language) are derived from those, and don't necessarily tell you exactly what the actual rules are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As `*` and `++` have same precedence

No, postfix `operator++` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator*`; then `*score_ptr++` is equivalent to `*(score_ptr++)`. Note that the [postfix `operator++`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec#Built-in_postfix_operators) would increment the operand and return the original value, then `*(score_ptr++)` would give the value `1`.

> The result is prvalue copy of the original value of the operand.

On the other hand prefix `operator++` returns incremented value. If you change the code to `*++score_ptr` (which is equivalent to `*(++score_ptr)`) then the result would be `2` (which might be what you expected).

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

The increment will happen first, it has higher precedence, it's equivalent to `*(score_ptr++)`, but it's a post-increment, this means it will only happen after the dereferenced pointer is used, i.e. the expression reaches `;`.

If you use

```
std::cout << *++score_ptr;
```

Then you have a pre-increment, here it will happen beforehand, the pointer will be incremented before the value is used and the output will be `2`. Equivalent to `*(++score_ptr)`.

**Note that it's allways a good idea to use parentheses, it will make the code clearer and will avoid missinterpretations.**